# BinaryReader, reading by blocks, ArgumentException, Offset and length were out of bounds

Tags: c#, .net, stream, binary

My stream has 1467 bytes, One block has 489 bytes, Address is 978 and I would like one block. So it is the last block in stream [from 978 to end of file]
But I give this Exception: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.

But why ? from 978 to 1467 is 489 bytes, and I try read 489 bytes from 978, so Why this exception is throwed ?

this is my code.

```
public List<Block<T>> ReadBlock(int address)
{
    var result = new List<Block<T>>();
    using (var br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read),Encoding.Default))
    {
         var buffer = new byte[BlockSize];
         br.Read(buffer, address, BlockSize);

         if (buffer.Sum(item => item) == 0)
         {
            result.Add(new Block<T>());
         }
         else
         {
            var block = new Block<T>();
            block.Deserialize(buffer);
            result.Add(block);
         }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `address` is the starting point in the `buffer`.

So your `buffer` length is 489 but you are trying to fill it starting at index 978 (out of bounds)

You will want to use `Seek` to move to the offset (address) before filling your buffer

```
var buffer = new byte[BlockSise];

// go to offset address 
br.BaseStream.Seek(address, SeekOrigin.Begin);

// fill buffer from starting at address to address + BlockSise
br.Read(buffer, 0, BlockSise);
```

That will fill `buffer` with `BlockSize` bytes starting at `address`